# Unity Intersections Mask

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, mask, intersection, plane

Is there any way to detect if an object with a certain amount of vertices hits a plane? If so, I want to draw it in binary (black/white) onto the plane or create a texture with it.

And I also don't care about if this can only be created with raycasts or some tricky physics operations / shaders / etc.. I'm just wondering what mathematical algorithm could create this.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Here is an example of what im trying to achieve]

Cheers, Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most games will achieve this with specialized shaders:

1. First pass renders a *depth map* for opaque objects in the scene
2. Second pass uses an *intersection shader* for transparent object(s)

The intersection shader looks for fragments where depth is equal (or nearly equal) to the depth from the first pass, then colors those fragments differently.

[A question on the Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111374/how-do-i-write-a-shader-that-lights-up-when-objects-are-near-a-surface) goes into more detail, including screenshots and a WebGL demo.

In your case, this might look like:

1. Render the plane as opaque geometry
2. Render the other objects using intersection shader

   - Fragments that intersect the plane are drawn
   - Fragments that do *not* intersect the plane are discarded

Whether you are doing this for an entire scene, or just to generate a texture that you can apply to some other object, the shader principles remain the same either way.

Comment: Could u maybe give me an example of this shader in unity.. im not that good with shaders?

Answer (score 2):

Writing the shader myself I stumbled across this Question so many times because google image search shows it every time.

I might be 4 years to late but for everyone else, I've written a shader that does exactly what's on the picture:

[image: Showcase]

Shader for the Wall (ShaderOne)

```
Shader "Custom/ShaderOne"
{
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry"}
            Pass {
            Stencil {
                Ref 2
                Comp always
                Pass replace 
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return half4(0.5,0.5,0.5,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    } 
}
```

Shader for the Object(s) (ShaderTwo)

```
Shader "Custom/ShaderTwo"
{
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {

            Stencil {
                Ref 2
                Comp equal
                Pass IncrWrap
                ZFail keep
            }

            ZTest less
            Cull Front
            ZWrite OFF

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert 
            #pragma fragment frag alpha
            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return half4(0,0,1,0.0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
   
        Pass {

            Stencil {
                Ref 2
                Comp equal
                Pass keep
                ZFail keep
            }

            ZTest less
            Cull Back
            ZWrite OFF

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return half4(1,0,0,0.5);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on a similar thread on unity forum:

The image link:
https://forum.unity.com/proxy.php?image=https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2FRnj-LM2i238HSMGSEhRUEn81M7TrdifT6WZziEU2LpwpAYShVkXbdpBImOSc4DSxlsGyaN6eTG1HWP9qKrG7E7StGGMgF4e27bHVLsoWvQXelyPw0fHhZ2fpRPeERg8twaeo3omd3Q%3Dw660-h558-no&hash=41a049afb39e6495d86db0ab14a8e936

The forum thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/intersection-shader-cull-front-minus-cull-back.536812/